# Pixelation issues on iPhone Air game

Tags: iphone, actionscript-3, air, scaling, adobe-illustrator

I am working on a cross-platform mobile game for Android and iOS devices.  I am using Adobe Flash with AIR and AS3 to code the game.  I am drawing my character, obstacles, and backgrounds in Adobe Illustrator.  The canvas in Flash is set to 960x640.  The character was intended to be 1/3 of the screen height so around 213 pixels high.  I designed the character in Adobe Illustrator to be somewhere around 900 pixels high.  When I imported the character into Flash I animated him, instantiated him using var player:Player = new Player(), and scaled him down to size using the scaleX and scaleY properties.  I tested it out on the desktop and Android phone and it looked wonderful.  However, when I tested it out on an iPhone, the player was unacceptably pixelated around the edges.  I figured the fact that I drew the animation much larger than the intended height must be the problem, so I redrew the player to exactly 213 pixels high and retested on the iPhone without any improvement in the quality of the animation.  I also tried converting the MovieClip to a Bitmap vector explained [here](http://sierakowski.eu/list-of-tips/86-building-mobile-games-in-adobe-air-optimization-techniques-used-in-jumping-droid-game.html) but that also had no effect on the quality of the animation.

[image: animation on an iPhone]

At this point, I am at a loss.  Does anyone have any suggestions on how to avoid this pixelation issue that I am experiencing when going from Adobe Illustrator to Flash to the iPhone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a more optimised iPhone route you might want to consider creating your animation as a set of bitmap graphics, i.e. create them as png files using PhotoShop at the size you want them to be displayed at.

By doing this you'll save CPU activity in having Flash create smoothed bitmaps

Comment: I'm not sure I see the benefit of using PhotoShop versus Illustrator to design the graphics.  Right now, I'm importing to Flash the design as a single bitmap object while keeping the layers and groups of shapes designated in Illustrator.  Are you saying that exporting the design as a png will improve the quality on the iPhone?

Comment: There was no benefit to using PhotoShop versus Illustrator.  They can both export PNGs at various DPI resolutions.  Anyway, the idea of using a set of bitmap graphics was a step in the right direction to fix the lag issue. I used the classes http://blog.vizio360.co.uk/2010/10/give-me-a-movieclip-ill-give-you-a-sequence-of-bitmaps/ to create my bitmap data vectors.  As far as the pixelation issue, I found that when publishing the iOS game, selecting the GPU rendering mode instead of the CPU rendering mode made a world of difference with respect to the quality of the objects on my stage.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set smoothing to true for your bitmap.

yourbitmap.smoothing = true;

Comment: When generating the bitmap vector, I applied the smoothing property as you suggested to each bitmap in the vector, yet that had no impact on the quality of the animation. :(

Answer (score 0):

I have some solutions for your problems.

1. Character should not have dark outlines.  Use gradients for better effects.
2. Color combination should understand for your character.  which background you use and other things.